# Safari Geolocation just refuses to work

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, safari, geolocation, mobile-safari

No matter what I do, the following code just never works when the location request popup opens in Safari. It works in every other browser I've tried so far (Chrome, Firefox, IE) but not on Safari desktop and mobile.

```
var Backbone    = require('backbone'),
    $           = require('jquery'),
    _           = require('underscore');


module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.directions',

    events: {
        'click #geo-choice': 'useGeoLocation',
        'click #provide-choice': 'sendManualLocation'
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.position = null;
        this.geoOptions = {
            enableHighAccuracy: true,
            timeout: 10000, // Allow 10 seconds before failing
            maximumAge: 60000 // Prevent trying again for multiple clicks from impatient users
        };

        this.$form = this.$('form');
        this.$input = this.$('input[name=saddr]');
        this.$postcode = this.$('input#postcode');
        this.$geoChoice = this.$('.geo.choice');
        this.$manualChoice = this.$('.provide.choice');

        Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);

        _.bindAll(this,
            'removeGeoLocation',
            'useGeoLocation',
            'sendManualLocation',
            'positionFound',
            'positionError',
            'showSpinner',
            'hideSpinner'
        );

        if (!'geolocation' in window.navigator) {
            this.removeGeoLocation();
        }
    },

    removeGeoLocation: function () {
        console.log('remove geo location option');
        this.$geoChoice.hide();
        this.$geoChoice.after('<p class="geo error">There was an error finding your location.</p>')
    },

    useGeoLocation: function () {
        this.showSpinner();

        if (this.position === null) {
            window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                this.positionFound,
                this.positionError,
                this.geoOptions
            );
        } else {
            this.sendGeoLocation();
        }
    },

    positionFound: function (position) {
        console.log(position);
        this.position = position;
        this.sendGeoLocation();
    },

    positionError: function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        this.hideSpinner();
        this.removeGeoLocation();
    },

    sendGeoLocation: function () {
        console.log('send location called', this.position);
        var that = this;
            var loc = that.position.coords.latitude + ', ' + that.position.coords.longitude;

            that.hideSpinner();
            that.$input.val(loc);
            // console.log('trigger', that.$form.trigger('submit'));
            // that.$form.trigger('submit');
            console.log('opening url');
            that.openUrl();
    },

    openUrl: function () {
        var url = this.$form.attr('action'),
            saddr = this.$('input[name=saddr]').val().replace(' ', '+'),
            daddr = this.$('input[name=daddr]').val().replace(' ', '+');

        url = url + '?saddr=' + saddr + '&daddr=' + daddr;
        console.log(url);

        var to = setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('timeout called');
            to = null;
            window.open(url, '_blank');
        }, 2000);
    },

    sendManualLocation: function () {
        this.hideSpinner();
        this.$input.val(this.$postcode.val());
        this.$form.trigger('submit');
    },

    showSpinner: function () {
        this.$('i.icon-spin').show();
    },

    hideSpinner: function () {
        this.$('i.icon-spin').hide();
    }
});
```

(this is a backbone module built in a node environment)

As you can see, I've added loads of `setTimeout`s to see if it was just tripping up while clearing a queue or something, but to no avail. All of the functions trigger, all of the console's log, but the `window.open` refuses to action in Safari only. I've even tried just submitting the form directly and that too fails.

If I click the button again after I've answered the popup, then it works, but this isn't great for users who may think my page has just bummed out :(

The user interacts with the popup, allowing use of the API, then it just prevents any window.open or form submit. I cannot figure out why.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? It's driving me crazy!

Thanks in advance for advice.

Comment: It's probably blocking the popup because you're triggering `window.open()` without direct user interaction.

Comment: but the popup isn't called until after the user interacts with it directly. Safari and Firefox hold the callback until the user says 'yes' and then trigger it, the difference is that Firefox allows the popup to open. Anyway, the form won't submit either.